# При уничтожении обьекта подвисает игра на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При уничтожении игрового объекта Destroy(gameobject); подвисает на секунду игра. Причина этому проклятая библиотека A* Pathfinding Project Выключая главный обьект этой библиотеки без которого она не работает все перестает подвисать. Беда в том что я долго писал игру в расчете на эту библиотеку, так как мне казалось так проще и не обращал внимание на подвисания, думая что этот баг и я его исправлю, но когда я в ужасе увидел, сколько я всего написал в расчете на эту библиотеку. Короче если кто-нибудь хорошо знаком с этой библиотекой под Unity, может что нибудь посоветует как уничтожить обьект так чтобы игра не зависала и не отказываться от библиотеки.

Comment: попробуй объект просто прятать, а не удалять. В любом случае можно удалять не немножку, а не все сразу.

Comment: Можно попробовать, вот только меня смущает то что у меня товер дефенс и если я допустим буду только прятать то слишком много объектов будет неудаленных

Comment: Для начала стоило бы открыть профайлер и посмотреть, что же, собственно, вызывает такие фризы. Никогда не поверю, что коммерческая библиотека будет фризить на секунду при удалении 1 агента вот просто на ровном месте.

Comment: А что за объекты? Может их можно использовать повторно? А удалять в конце волны, когда небольшой фриз не критичен?

Comment: В принципе все понятно это из-за библиотеки, самое простое обьяснение она пересчитывает квадратики при уничтожении или появл обьекта, а этих квадратиков я сильно много выставил, буду выставлять меньше, работать.СПС за ответы постараюсь написать решение, когда сделаю.